# Single Submit button for forms in different Views in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, textbox

I am using a JavaScript function on click to submit multiple forms in my MVC View. Following is  my view. But the forms are not submitting. Script followed by two forms and then button having JS function assigned on-click.

```
<script>
function submitForms() {
    document.getElementById("server1form").submit();
    document.getElementById("server2form").submit();


}
            </script>

<div> 
        @model BTSWeb.Models.DropDownModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id="server1form"}))
{
    <label style="color:black">    Type the name of the server you want to use.    (Example - test-babyadept):         
 </label>
        <span style="margin-left:80px"></span>  

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.server1)
       <input  type="submit" value="server1"  />
}

<br>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "server2form" }))
{
    <label style="color:black">    If you wish you compare the results from two servers. Type the name of second server:
 </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.server2)
       <input  type="submit" value="server2"  />
}    <br>
<br>


<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Find Billable Account" onclick="submitForms()"     />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood what you are trying to achieve then you should simply incorporate the two textboxes from the second view into your first view (within the form tags), expand your model and when you submit the form it will submit everything to your action to process as you wish?  Let me know if I have the wrong end of the stick?